# \frac{}{} won't work for me w/ pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

I'm rather new at using python and especially numpy, and matplotlib.  Running the code below (which works fine without the `\frac{}{}` part) yields the error:

```
Normalized Distance in Chamber ($
                             rac{x}{L}$)
                            ^
Expected end of text (at char 32), (line:1, col:33)
```

The math mode seems to work fine for everything else I've tried (symbols mostly, e.g. `$\mu$` works fine and displays µ) so I'm not sure what is happening here.  I've looked up other peoples code for examples and they just seem to use `\frac{}{}` with nothing special and it works fine.  I don't know what I'm doing differently.  Here is the code.  Thanks for the help!

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

[ ... bunch of calculations ... ]

plt.plot(xspace[:]/L,vals[:,60])
plt.axis([0,1,0,1])
plt.xlabel('Normalized Distance in Chamber ($\frac{x}{L}$)')
plt.savefig('test.eps')
```

Also, I did look up \f and it seems its an "escape character", but I don't know what that means or why it would be active within TeX mode.

Comment: Did you try adding a an `r` in front of your string, to make it raw?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In many languages, backslash-letter is a way to enter otherwise hard-to-type characters. In this case it's a "form feed". Examples:

```
\n — newline
\r — carriage return
\t — tab character
\b — backspace
```

To disable that, you either need to escape the backslash itself (backslash-backslash is a backslash)

```
'Normalized Distance in Chamber ($\\frac{x}{L}$)'
```

Or use "raw" strings where escape sequences are disabled:

```
r'Normalized Distance in Chamber ($\frac{x}{L}$)'
```

This is relevant to Python, not TeX.

[Documentation on Python string literals](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Answer (score 3):

`"\f"` is a form-feed character in Python.  TeX never sees the backslash because Python interprets the `\f` in your Python source, before the string is sent to TeX.  You can either double the backslash, or make your string a raw string by using `r'Normalized Distance ... etc.'`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an `r` front of the string to avoid parsing the `\f`.