# raw input through tkinter entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, raw-input, tkinter-entry

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
window = Tk()

entryBox = Entry(window,text='input latex command')
entryBox.grid(row=0,column=0)

s = '$\sum {n} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$'
plt.text(.5,.5, s, fontsize=40)
plt.show()
```

This snippet displays only a part of the expression as follows:
[image]

instead of the expected result:

[image]

(This is achieved by changing the 7th line as: `plt.text(.3,.3, r'$\sum {n} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$', fontsize=40)`).

My understanding is that in the first case we are not passing the string as a raw string. How can I get the plot to render correctly when I have the string as a string variable but cannot input it as a string literal?

Comment: If you write `s = r'$\sum {n} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$'` (i.e. add the `r` in front of the string), it works as expected.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7262828/2454357).

Comment: Why couldn't you input it as a string literal?

Comment: I meant I could not pass the string as a literal because the string is coming through the entry widget. @Nae

Answer (score 0):

Filter your string using:

```
s = s.replace("\x0c", "\\f")
```

as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262918/7032856) [doesn't work on frac formfeed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16002862/7032856) apparently.